# Get aggregation with term frequency in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, search, lucene

Here is my ES Queries:

=== Create the index ===

```
PUT /sample
```

=== Insert Data ===

```
PUT /sample/docs/1
{"data": "And the world said, 'Disarm, disclose, or face serious consequences'—and therefore, we worked with the world, we worked to make sure that Saddam Hussein heard the message of the world."}
PUT /sample/docs/2
{"data": "Never give in — never, never, never, never, in nothing great or small, large or petty, never give in except to convictions of honour and good sense. Never yield to force; never yield to the apparently overwhelming might of the enemy"}
```

=== Query to Get Results ===

```
POST sample/docs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "data": "never"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "data":{}
    }
  }
}
```

=== Retrieved Result ===

```
...
        "highlight": {
          "data": [
            "<em>Never</em> give in — <em>never</em>, <em>never</em>, <em>never</em>, <em>never</em>, in nothing great or small, large or petty, <em>never</em> give",
            " in except to convictions of honour and good sense. <em>Never</em> yield to force; <em>never</em> yield to the apparently overwhelming might of the enemy"
          ]
        }
```

=== Desired Result===

Required Term Frequency of searched term by document
as example below

```
Doc Id: 2
Term Frequency :{
    "never": 8
}
```

I have tried Bucket Aggregation, Terms Aggregation and other Aggregations but I'm not getting this result.

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Term Vector, which supports querying a particular term based on the frequency.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html

In such case, your query would be

```
GET /sample/docs/_termvectors
{
    "doc": {
      "data": "never"
    },
    "term_statistics" : true,
    "field_statistics" : true,
    "positions": false,
    "offsets": false,
    "filter" : {
      "min_term_freq" : 8
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting following error if I execute your suggested query:
`{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
        "reason": "Something is wrong with the field statistics of the term vector request: Values are \nsum_doc_freq 0\ndoc_count 0\nsum_ttf 0"
      }
    ],
    "type": "illegal_state_exception",
    "reason": "Something is wrong with the field statistics of the term vector request: Values are \nsum_doc_freq 0\ndoc_count 0\nsum_ttf 0"
  },
  "status": 500
}`

Comment: And My need is different as per your suggested query it will return results with term frequency of 8 but What I want in result is number of term frequency.

Comment: any progress on this @iKishanSojitra?